# Double integration problem

Tags: calculus

I have a problem regarding the integration below:

$$\Omega : x^{2}+y^{2}\le1$$
$$\iint_{\Omega } (1-x^{2}-y^{2}) dxdy=?$$

How to integrate this? Could anyone give me a hint? Thank you

Thanks for the hint.

How about if $$\Omega : \frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}\le1$$
$$\iint_{\Omega } (1-\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}-\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}) dxdy=?$$

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Polar coordinates.

Comment: Did you mean $x^2+y^2\le1$?

Comment: @David, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the elipsis have a transformation $u=\frac xa,v=\frac yb$, reduce it to the other problem and solve it.  <del>Answer should be $\frac13ab\pi$.</del>

**Correction:** Answer should be $\frac12ab\pi$.

Comment: I was trying to reparameterize it to  x=acos(theta), y=bsin(theta), and the integrand becomes zero? that's why I got but I don't think it's correct...

Comment: What you are doing by the first integration is to find the volume bellow the surface $z=1-x^2-y^2$ (and above the $xy$-plane).  By having $r^2=x^2+y^2$ you have $z=1-r^2$  This should be $V=\frac12\pi$ (but you must do your homework, this is just to check your result).  The second integral is a space transformation from the unitary circle (as base of your solid) to an ellipsis of axes $a$ and $b$.

Comment: thanks for the patience. the first one I get it, but the second one, why it doesn't work if I reparameterize like what I said in the first comment?

Comment: You are not reparameterizing, by $x=a\sin\theta,y=b\cos\theta$ you are describing the border of your solid at $z=0$.

Comment: I think I get your point!! but is this the only way to solve this question? that use the substitution and then do the transformation? Thanks~

Comment: There are several ways, v.g. you can integrate through the $z$-axis (which is how I came to the answer) or use many other transformation techniques.  Some are simpler and some will give you complexly big expressions.  If you already have the first integral the proposed transformation is the quickest.

Answer (score 1):

As @daniel Fischer says, polar coordinates.

$$r^2=x^2+y^2$$
$$dx \, dy = r \, dr \, d\theta$$

where $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$.

I get $\pi/2$ for the result.